# I'm implementing a background gradient overlay over a bootstrap card, but the title text gets the background overlay as well

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

[image]

The following is my HTML markup where I add the title as a prop for Bootstrap card. I've tried z-index as well, but I wasn't able to achieve the desired result.

```
<b-col>
              <div class="card-container">
                <b-card
                  overlay
                  img-src="/images/ajm.jpg"
                  img-alt="Card Image"
                  class="product-card"
                  title="Linear Motors"
                  title-tag="h5"
                  align="center"
                ></b-card>
              </div>
            </b-col>
```

CSS ----->

```
.product-card {
  height: 353px;
  border-radius: 0px;
  border: 0;
  color: #0c1c35;
}

.card-container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  :hover {
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(
      90deg,
      hsla(217, 100%, 50%, 1) 0%,
      hsla(186, 100%, 69%, 1) 100%
    );
    opacity: 0.8;
    color: white;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Another thought I had was that the opacity field actually effects child elements as explained in w3 schools:

`If you do not want to apply opacity to child elements, like in our example above, use RGBA color values. The following example sets the opacity for the background color and not the text:`

From seeing your CSS I see you're using opacity, so this might work if you use the RGBA - CSS.

```
.card-container { 
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5); 
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for your response, I've tried these approaches but I get the same effect. I've added my CSS above.

Comment: Hi thanks again for your response, I applied the rgba values to :hover and it worked.